# Linux startup scripts

Tags: boot, xorg, openbox, autostart

Background: I am running an Arch Linux build on my laptop. The system has been sitting there for three years. I've re-installed a couple of times, and I carried over the old dot files in my home directory during the re-installations. This makes it almost impossible for me to tell / remember all the configurations I've done. I use openbox as WM and haven't got any desktop environment on top of that.

Now I want to something simple:

I want the computer to run `tint2` on startup. To do this I did a search and learned `~/.xinitrc` runs whenever an I run startx, and `~/.config/openbox/autostart` is executed upon the running of openbox.

So I first made my `.xinitrc` into just two lines:

```
exec openbox
tint2 &
```

Then ran `pkill x` and `startx` again, openbox ran as always, but not tint2.

So why let us just try `autostart` then. I wrote a one-liner `autostart`

```
tint2 &
```

Reboot X, nothing happened.

I also `chmod +x`d the autostart script and tried changing the line to

```
(sleep 2s && tint2) &
```

but openbox kept refusing showing me the tint2 taskbar on startup.

If I run autostart script in a terminal window then it works.

My guess is, some other config files / scripts are executed instead. If that is the case, is there any way to tell which files they are? Or simply, why does the xinitrc or autostart script not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the

```
exec openbox
```

with

```
openbox-session
```

in `.xinitrc`. Turns out the `autostart` only runs with `openbox-session`.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to do a crude .xinitrc is to have it structured like

> process1 &
>   process2 &
>   process3 &
>   ... 
>   lastprocess

The last process, without the ampersand, is the "magic process," and closing it closes X. Traditionally, in twm, the magic process was an xterm. When the process without an ampersand ends, X closes. If you background the last process (`process4 &`), X will close. I think your example should look like:

> tint2 &
>   exec openbox-session

At least in some cases, I find omitting the ampersand doesn't seem to matter.  I do it by accident now and then with no ill effect.

Also make sure to do `chmod u+x .xinitrc`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the rule says "accept an answer if it solved the problem", so I accepted my own answer.